# Configuring Nunit with ASP.NET MVC Core 1.0

Tags: c#, tdd, nunit, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I wanted to configure NUnit for my ASP.NET Core 1.0 project. I have tried following : http://www.alteridem.net/2015/11/04/testing-net-core-using-nunit-3/
, but it's there for console applications.

If I try to attach a new project (class library) to my solution and then try to reference my original project - it gives me reference error.

Here is what worked for me:

1. I attached another web app project, dedicated to writing tests, to my original project, as opposed to the console library project.
2. Then I downloaded NuGet packages for : "dotnet-test-nunit", "NUnit", "NUnit.Console" and "NUnit.Runners".
3. Then I wrote a test which worked after adding this line to project.json:  `"testRunner": "nunit"`

This is the project.json file from my test project:

`

```
 {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "JustForTest": "1.0.0-*",
    "NUnit": "3.4.1",
    "NUnit.Runners": "3.4.1",
    "NUnit.Console": "3.4.1",
    "dotnet-test-nunit": "3.4.0-beta-2"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
  "testRunner": "nunit",
  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}`
```

**I have following questions:**

1. It don't seems like an optimized process - how can I optimize this?
2. Why test didn't worked with console application, could something be done to make that work?

Any help will be much appreciated. I am new to TDD and for that matter programming in C# - if you have any suggestion in this context, kindly share that as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `NUnit.Runners` or `NUnit.Console` NuGet packages. The post on my blog that you are following is for using `NUnitLite` which was the only way to write .NET Core unit tests with NUnit early on. Since then, `dotnet-test-nunit` is the way to go. It integrates with Visual Studio allowing you to run your tests from the Test Explorer window or from the command line using the `dotnet test` command.

Your unit test project should just be a .NET Core Class Library, not a console application or web app. The high level steps are,

1. Add a .NET Core Class Library project to your solution
2. Add the `dotnet-test-nunit` and `NUnit` NuGet packages to the project
3. Reference your web app from your test project
4. Write some tests
5. Run your tests from Visual Studio

For a more detailed walkthrough, read my newer blog post on [Writing NUnit 3 Tests for .NET Core and ASP.NET Core](http://www.alteridem.net/2016/06/18/nunit-3-testing-net-core-rc2/).

You should also look at the [ASP.NET Core documentation for Integration Testing](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/testing/integration-testing.html) that will give you hints on how to setup a test server and make sure your `Startup` code gets executed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your blog really helped while displaying step by step process.

Comment: I must thank you as well Rob, my tests are running in Visual Studio fine. I cannot seem to get them to run on VSTS / Visual Studio Online though. All the articles I have found suggest working with test adapter nuget packages - none of which are supported under .net core.

Comment: I tried full implementation for local and VSTS use of NUnit,  MSTest and xUnit and found xUnit the best supported - details and links at http://stackoverflow.com/q/40093573/2579219