# Why Test Explorer doesn't see my NUnit tests for ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nunit

Visual Studio 2017, .Net CoreApp 1.1 (the target framework)

I need to write NUnit tests for my *ASP.NET Core MVC* web-application. I often used NUnit for my desktop-projects which were build on the base of .NET Framework 3.5-4.6.1.

I haven't the problem with `xunit` but I would like to use `nunit`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39763452/configuring-nunit-with-asp-net-mvc-core-1-0) I saw that at the current case I am to include such NuGet-packages:

- *dotnet-test-nunit*
- *NUnit*

But Test Explorer doesn't see my tests:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ProductTests {

    [Test]
    public void Name_Gets_ValidValue() {

        var name = "Bob";
        decimal price = 45.5M;

        Product p = new Product() { Name = name, Price = price };

        Assert.AreEqual(name, p.Name);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Name_Gets_ValidPrice() {

        var name = "Bob";
        decimal price = 45.5M;

        Product p = new Product() { Name = name, Price = price };

        Assert.AreEqual(price, p.Price);
    }
}
```

Hm... Ok. I tried to add *NUnit3TestAdapter* NuGet-package (I use it alwais), but this problem doesn't disappear.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When .NET Core switched from the `project.json` format to the `csproj` format, it dropped support for the original .NET Core test adapter API, so the `dotnet-test-nunit` adapter no longer works with Visual Studio 2017 or the new .NET Core command line tools.

The new `csproj` format uses the old Visual Studio test adapter API, so the NUnit team needed to update that test adapter to support .NET Core. That work is nearly done in two PR's, one for the [Visual Studio adapter](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/pull/313) and one for the [NUnit Engine](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/pull/205).

Once those two pull requests are merged, I will be creating an alpha release of the updated adapter, hopefully next week. Once I do so, I will update my blog with the new way to setup unit tests for .NET Core. In the meantime, you could [make your unit tests self-executing using NUnitLite](http://www.alteridem.net/2016/05/18/testing-net-core-rc2-using-nunit-3/).

Sorry for the inconvenience, it took us longer than expected for the port to .NET Core.

**Update:** I have released an update to the NUnit Visual Studio Adapter that supports .NET Core. For information on how to use it, see [Testing .NET Core with NUnit in Visual Studio 2017](http://www.alteridem.net/2017/05/04/test-net-core-nunit-vs2017/)

Comment: Thank you. Is *"that test adapter"* the NUnit3TestAdapter?

Comment: Yes, it is the NUnit3TestAdapter. It's being upgraded to support .NET Core.